# Why can't the compiler infer my variable is not unassigned?

Tags: c#

Whenever an `if` statement is bulky (alot of conditions to check), I like to declare a boolean and assign it all the conditions, so that the if statement is as simple as `if(conditions)` such as in the code sample below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] ages = new int[] { 20, 21, 22 };
    int age;

    bool conditions =
        ages.Length > 0 &&
        (age = ages[0]) > 21;
    if (conditions)
    {
        // cs0165 use of unassigned local variable 'age'
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

But moving the conditions to a boolean is confusing the C# compiler; it doesn't understand that `age` is always assigned to. I need to write it as follows to avoid the error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] ages = new int[] { 20, 21, 22 };
    int age;

    if (ages.Length > 0 && (age = ages[0]) > 21)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

Why can't the compiler infer it's assigned to, in the original case?

Comment: @NathanHughes: I disagree with the "horrible style" part. Often if I have (say) 6 conditions that must be true, but they naturally break down into two sub-conditions each with three conditions, I'll introduce two explanatory variables to make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @Jon: sorry i specifically meant the assignment crammed into the middle of the conditions. So that the variable is assigned only some of the time. No complaint with intermediate assignments otherwise.

Comment: The *why* is less satisfying then the *how*. The *why* is simply because that's the way they wrote it. The *how* is a trip through the specification

Comment: It just doesn't take your word for it that ages.Length > 0.  Even you did not by testing for it, what was the point??  Remove the test and it will be happy.

Comment: I think this comes down to a trade off in static analysis, between the time it would take to check every path in every way, and the benefit,

Comment: *moving the conditions to a boolean is confusing the C# compiler* - forget the compiler; writing code like this will confuse **your fellow developers** - as a human, I have to back track back through 3 different statements to work out what `conditions` and `age` are set to; that's an awful way to write code. I'd recommend you make it cleaner, easier to read and more self documenting. Code that relies on "an assignment returns the value that was assigned" is nearly always not worth doing in terms of human confusion. I'm sure on the surface it looks like a neat trick, but I'd always avoid it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't the compiler infer it's assigned?

Because it doesn't use variables like that, even if sometimes we might want it to. Or rather, this isn't really about what the *compiler* does, so much as what the C# specification and standard require.

Within the `if` statement condition, the assignment state of `age` becomes "definitely assigned after true expression" which means that within the `if` statement *body*, it's definitely assigned. But the standard and compiler don't extend that to "well we assigned the value to this variable, and nothing else will have changed the value of that variable, so if the variable is true then the expression must have been true too", so it should be definitely assigned.

The details of this are in the [ECMA C# 5 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm), section 10.4, and in particular 10.4.4.6. Best of luck - it's all a bit hairy...

Comment: Since it is a compile time error, so looks like C# compiler compiles the code block by block, "age" will be assigned at run time so in first case the use of this variable is in a different piece of code that caused the error But in second case assignment of "age" variable is part of the same block where it is being used. Just a quick analysis without an insight view.

Comment: @RashidAli: It's not a matter of the compiler acting block-by-block. It's about what the specification requires. If the language designers *wanted* to allow this to work - at the cost of a more complex specification - they could have required that, and the compiler would have handled it. It's a matter of design, not implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Because it might not be assigned.  If the first condition fails `ages.Length` it seems like the next expression won't be evaluated: `age = ...`

See the [boolean logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) reference for C#

Comment: It won't enter the branch if either of the conditions fail; the compiler is missing (in the 1st example, but not the 2nd) that if the branch is entered, `age` MUST have been assigned to.